# Python: How to catch inner exception of exception chain?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Consider the simple example:

```
def f():
    try:
        raise TypeError
    except TypeError:
        raise ValueError

f()
```

I want to catch `TypeError` object when `ValueError` is thrown after `f()` execution. Is it possible to do it?

If I execute function `f()` then python3 print to stderr all raised exceptions of exception chain ([PEP-3134](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/)) like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 6, in f
    raise TypeError
TypeError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 11, in <module>
    f()
  File "...", line 8, in f
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

So I would get the list of all exceptions of exception chain **or** check if exception of some type (`TypeError` in the above example) exists in exception chain.

Comment: I guess it's an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Real question to ask: what exactly are you trying to achieve here (not _how_ you want to achieve that)?

Answer (score 23):

Python 3 has a beautiful syntactic enhancement on exceptions handling. Instead of plainly raising ValueError, you should raise it from a caught exception, i.e.:

```
try:
    raise TypeError('Something awful has happened')
except TypeError as e:
    raise ValueError('There was a bad value') from e
```

Notice the difference between the tracebacks. This one uses `raise from` version:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/tmp.py", line 2, in <module>
    raise TypeError('Something awful has happened')
TypeError: Something awful has happened

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/tmp.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise ValueError('There was a bad value') from e
ValueError: There was a bad value
```

Though the result may seem similar, in fact it is rather different! `raise from` saves the context of the original exception and allows one to trace all the exceptions chain back - which is impossible with simple `raise`.

To get the original exception, you simply have to refer to new exception's `__context__` attribute, i.e.

```
try:
    try:
        raise TypeError('Something awful has happened')
    except TypeError as e:
        raise ValueError('There was a bad value') from e
except ValueError as e:
    print(e.__context__)
>>> Something awful has happened
```

Hopefully that is the solution you were looking for.

For more details, see [PEP 3134 -- Exception Chaining and Embedded Tracebacks](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/)

Comment: Thanks. To get exception objects from caugth `ValueError as e` need to call: `e.__cause__` that returns `TypeError` object. If the `TypeError` object (let `e2`) has cause-exception object then it can be got by `e2.__cause__`, etc. The generator `def cause_gen(exc): yield exc; while exc.__cause__: exc = exc.__cause__; yield exc;` returns all exceptions of exception chain where argument is init caught exception.

Comment: So is it impossible to get exceptions if they were raised without `from` (impossible to edit source code)?

Comment: Unfortunately not without dirty/hacky code which emulates `raise from`. If you are bound to Py2, there is a backport in *future* library. Essentially the PEP was introduced in order to handle the very impossibility of getting the inner exceptions.

Comment: In python 3 stderr contains all exceptions of exception chain even if `raise from` is not used (as it was described in the question). So I think that it's possible to get them in this case. E.g. direct way: parsing stderr output as string. Is there no other way?

Comment: @kupgov: I've been searching everywhere for the answer of your exact question, that is, how do I get the original exception object if "raise from" is not used? In my case the exception is generated by an underlying .net dll file, so adding "raise from" is not an option. Did you get an answer in the end?

Comment: @Uffe No, I didn't. Dirty way as it's described above - parsing stderr string.